# Proper way to set an explicit transaction in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure that has 9 inserts in summarized tables and the last statement is a delete.

This procedure takes around 9 minutes to execute for each given date, and one thing that I noticed is that if an error occurs and the first 3 inserts executed, it keeps the inserted data. To handle this, I created a begin try and begin transaction and a test that I did was to start the procedure using SSMS and after it started, I cancelled the command but the transaction was kept. How can I avoid this?

the procedure body is very simple... something like:

```
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
insert into...
delete from....
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) The basic syntax is:

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN

  INSERT...

  DELETE...

  COMMIT TRAN

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
  END

  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
  SET @ErrorMessage = 'Line ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ERROR_LINE()) + ': '
                    + ERROR_MESSAGE()
  RAISERROR(@SQLErrString, 16, 1)

END CATCH
```

2) If you cancel a batch in process, you might need to run the ROLLBACK TRAN manually.  You can test if you need to do this by doing a SELECT @@TRANCOUNT and if it is > 0 then call ROLLBACK TRAN.